# How to use sqlcounter to disconnect a user after reaching the monthly quota?

Tags: freeradius

I'm new to Freeradius. My NAS is StrongSwan and seems to be [supporting](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/EAPRAdius) CoA.
I also have the sql accounting mod enabled, which allows me to count the octets.

There are many tutorials about how to count the session time of a user and action a session-timeout once the time is over. But virtually there is nothing I could find that explains how to count the user's data usage and disconnect him after let say 100 KB of monthly usage.

**vim /etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/sqlcounter**

```
sqlcounter totaldatacounter {
        sql_module_instance = sql
        dialect = ${modules.sql.dialect}

        counter_name = Max-Capacity
        check_name = Acct-Output-Octets
        reply_name = Session-Timeout

        key = User-Name
        reset = monthly
        query = "SELECT ((SUM(`acctinputoctets`)+SUM(`acctoutputoctets`))) FROM radacct WHERE `username`='%{${key}}' AND Month(acctstoptime)=(Month(NOW())) AND Year(acctstoptime)=Year(NOW())"
}
```

When I run the query above for the given user I get the following data usage: `76827648`

This is more than my limit of `100000` set in `radcheck` table:

```
INSERT INTO `radcheck` (`id`, `username`, `attribute`, `op`, `value`)
VALUES
    (3, '0799a559-1426-478a-b46a-a33f1198cd24', 'Acct-Output-Octets', ':=', '100000');
```

So why am still able to connect?

I have a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ydELgnvH) here of the `freeradius -X` logfile.